# Pretty printing in jq

Tags: jq

`jq .` has the side-effect of pretty printing the input.

```bash
$ echo '{"foo":"bar", "baz":[1,2,3]}' | jq .
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

But if I want to use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to incorporate the input with some surrounding text, the input renders compactly

```bash
$ echo '{"foo":"bar", "baz":[1,2,3]}' | jq -r '"My value is:\n\(.)\nSome other stuff"'
My value is:
{"foo":"bar","baz":[1,2,3]}
Some other stuff
```

Is there any way to force pretty printing here? I'd like the output to be

```
My value is:
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
Some other stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

I did find a solution while I was writing the question: don't put the input inside string interpolation, output a stream of things:

```bash
echo '{"foo":"bar", "baz":[1,2,3]}' | jq -r '"My value is:", . , "Some other stuff"'
# .........................................................^^^^^
```

outputs

```
My value is:
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
Some other stuff
```

Comment: This is the way I would have done it myself. If you want to control the newlines around the pretty-printed JSON (as you did with your `jq -r '"…\n\(.)\n…"'` approach), use the `-j` option with the stream approach: `jq -j '"…\n", ., "\n…\n"'`. This way, by omitting the according newlines, you can place text on the same line as the first or the last line of the pretty-printed JSON.

Comment: For posterity: `--join-output` / `-j`: "Like -r but jq won't print a newline after each output."

Answer (score 0):

This might not fit your actual use case, but instead of creating a single JSON string in `jq`, just use a shell command group.

```
echo '{"foo":"bar", "baz":[1,2,3]}' | { echo "My value is:"; jq .; echo "Some other stuff"; }
```

Comment: I'm hand-waving over a bunch of logic embedded in the jq code (the "other stuff").

Comment: Maybe that could just be a separate call to `jq`, though that would probably require using `tee` and it could get ugly fast. I'm thinking of this in terms of pretty-printing not being any kind of filter that transforms JSON, but a feature of `jq` itself *after* any filters (even the trivial filter `.`) have been applied.